# Can AWS codebuild build a project using two repos?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a node application, the code is in a AWS codecommit repo. To build this app I need parameters coming from an .env file. I put this .env file in another codecommit repo.

I would like to know if AWS codebuild can pull the code from the two repos in order to build the app correctly, and how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add multiple sources to your CodeBuild project. Go to your project -> Edit -> Source -> Add Source.

You need to provide a source identifier for your secondary source and you can access the folder where the second source is downloaded using the environment variable `$CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_<sourceIdentifer>` in your buildspec.

You can add the first codecommit source with your node application code and configure the secondary source with identifier `CONFIG_REPO`. In your buildspec, you can copy the .env file to the root of your node application code by doing something like below :

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - ls -lart $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR # lists your node repo
      - ls -lart $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_CONFIG_REPO # lists your config repo
      - cp $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_CONFIG_REPO/.env .
```

Answer (score 2):

I was under the impression that CodeBuild can only have one source and the best way to manage multiple CodeBuild jobs was through IaC.

However, it seems it is possible to have multiple sources:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-multi-in-out.html